# mb_convert_encoding Not working

Tags: php, x-cart

I am using `mb_convert_encoding` for converting texts entered by the user (to utf-8 format) in a X cart site. But when I was trying to run the code the execution terminates at the encoding point. The following code is what I am using for conversion:

```
mb_convert_encoding($str,"iso-8859-7");
```

I even checked the `phpinfo` and the `mbstring` is enabled there. I don't know whether I need to enable any other settings?. Any help on this will be much appreciated.

**Updated** : There is one more thing that I missed. We are also converting Greek letters and we don't know whether `mb_convert_encoding` supports Greek letters.

Comment: `the execution terminates at the encoding code`. Does it terminate with any kind of error message?

Comment: No Joachim Isaksson, it doesn't give any error messages after terminates. I even checked the error log and can't find any error messages related to this.

Answer (score 0):

Check your error log, it will give you plentyful loads of detail on the problem.

On UNIX systems like Linux it is usually configured to be at `/var/log/apache2/error.log` or `/var/log/httpd/error.log`.